# Which metric spaces are isometric to $(\mathbb{R}^n, d_E)$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Which metric spaces are isometric to $(\mathbb{R}^n, d_E)$?

Two metric spaces $(M_1, d_1)$ and $(M_2, d_2)$ are called isometric, when an isometry between them exists. An isometry is an isomorphism $\varphi: M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ such that

$$\forall p_1, p_2 \in M_1: d_1(p_1, p_2) = d_2(\varphi(p_1), \varphi(p_2))$$

is true.

Comment: I think it's only isometric to itself. Isn't this an old Banach result?

Comment: I wouldnt think so. Multiplying the euclidean metric with a constant C > 0 yields a different metric, but you could easily find an isometry for this case.

Comment: @moose in your definition of isometry, I think you want $f$ to be a bijection, or else there could be some alien points in $M$ that do not correspond to any points in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for besides "the metric spaces which are isometric to $(\mathbb{R}^n, d_E)$"?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi E.g. "All isometric spaces are only $(R^n, c \cdot d_E)$, where $c>0$" is a constant or some more exotic metrics which are isometric. Or some other connection. A criterion which I can use to tell if a metric is "basically" only the Euclidean metric. These kinds of answers.